# Перевод текста из молитвы на современный язык

Tags: старославянский

"... и имиже веси судьбами сокрый нас..." Подскажите, пожалуйста, что это значит на современном языке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "... и имиже веси судьбами сокрый
> нас..." Подскажите, пожалуйста, что
> это значит на современном языке.

По-моему, так:

*…и какими ты сам знаешь путями/способами укрой нас...*